# Pyspark retain value across rows?

Tags: pyspark, sas, window, retain

I have a problem which is naturally solved using a row-by-row SAS approach, but I'm stuck using Pyspark. I have a dataset of events for people ordered by time, for example:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'event_list':[["H"], ["H"], ["H","F"], ["F"], ["F"], ["H"], ["W"], ["W"]], 'time_order':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'person':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]})
test_df = spark.createDataFrame(test_df)
test_df.show()

+----------+----------+------+
|event_list|time_order|person|
+----------+----------+------+
|       [H]|         1|     1|
|       [H]|         2|     1|
|    [H, F]|         3|     1|
|       [F]|         4|     1|
|       [F]|         5|     1|
|       [H]|         6|     1|
|       [W]|         7|     1|
|       [W]|         8|     1|
+----------+----------+------+
```

I want to group these events into episodes where all events following the initial event are part of the initial event list. Therefore in my test_df I would expect 3 episodes:

```
+----------+----------+------+-------+
|event_list|time_order|person|episode|
+----------+----------+------+-------+
|       [H]|         1|     1|      1|
|       [H]|         2|     1|      1|
|    [H, F]|         3|     1|      2|
|       [F]|         4|     1|      2|
|       [F]|         5|     1|      2|
|       [H]|         6|     1|      2|
|       [W]|         7|     1|      3|
|       [W]|         8|     1|      3|
+----------+----------+------+-------+
```

In SAS I would retain the prior row's value for `event_list`, and if the current event_list is contained in the prior event_list, I would retain the current event_list value rather than the prior event_list. E.g. my retained values would be [null, ["H"], ["H"], ["H","F"], ["H","F"], ["H","F"], ["W"]]. Then I can generate the episodes by tracking changes in the retained values.

In Pyspark I'm not sure how to retain information sequentially across row operations...is this even possible? My attempts using window functions (partitioning by `person` and ordering by `time_order`) have failed. How can I solve this problem in Pyspark?

Comment: what spark version you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using spark version >= 2.4, use `collect_list` on *event_list* column over window, `flatten` them, remove duplicates using `array_distinct` and finally use `size` to count how many distinct events over time. It would be something like this :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, collect_list, flatten, array_distinct, size
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('person').orderBy('time_order').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

test_df = test_df.withColumn('episode', size(array_distinct(flatten(collect_list(col('event_list')).over(w)))))
test_df.show()

+----------+----------+------+-------+
|event_list|time_order|person|episode|
+----------+----------+------+-------+
|       [H]|         1|     1|      1|
|       [H]|         2|     1|      1|
|    [H, F]|         3|     1|      2|
|       [F]|         4|     1|      2|
|       [F]|         5|     1|      2|
|       [H]|         6|     1|      2|
|       [W]|         7|     1|      3|
|       [W]|         8|     1|      3|
+----------+----------+------+-------+
```